# SQL query, simple LEFT JOIN substraction

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

I have a very simple query, but somehow it fails, im pretty sure its just a syntax error, but I can find the error... Its very simular to this example below.. I want every that ONLY exists in TableA and not TableB or combined.

```
Select a.*
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b
ON a.key = b.key
WHERE b.key IS NULL
```

Comment: can you provide the error message you are receiving?

Comment: Im not getting any errors, it just turns up with 0 records, but I know thats not the correct answer.

Comment: It was a logic issue then, not syntax - as you have shown in your answer below, changing the logic solved the issue.  I believe the issue was from your WHERE statement, which required b.key to be null, which means it would only pull null values from TableA.

Comment: But this logic just works in all other normal mysql databases, so i thought i make was the b.key is null that need to be b.key = null or 'null'

Comment: Could be. My statement above was just a quick guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found another solution what works.

```
select * 
from TableA 
where key not in (
  select key from TableB)
```